# Is there a way to run Jupyter Notebooks Without Anaconda?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I deleted Anaconda because it was causing more issues than solving in working with other editors like Sublime, PyCharm, etc...

In class, we have a lot of Jupyter notebooks.  Is there a program that allows me to run Jupyter Notebooks just like Anaconda allowed me to?  Basically the same User Interface where Cntrl + Enter runs a block a code?

Thanks.

Edit: I figured it out. I needed to downgrade Python from 3.8 to 3.7

Comment: Yes Jupyter is a standalone program.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to downgrade Python, that's why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 10):

Jupyter can be installed separately to Anaconda using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) via `pip3 install jupyter` - see the [Jupyter](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id4) page for more information.