# Can't run Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, jupyter-notebook

I installed **Jupyter Notebook** using `pip install notebook` but I am not able to run it.

When I try runing using `jupyter notebook`, it gives me the `CommandNotFoundException`:
[image: Error when running 'jupyter notebook']

and

When I try runing using `python -m notebook`, it gives me the `ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython'`:
[image: Error when running 'python -m notebook']

I have added the following into PATH:

1. Path to python.exe present inside local folder.
2. Path to scripts folder present inside local folder.
3. Path to scripts folder present inside roaming folder.

All the jupyter dependencies(jupyter.exe, jupyter-core.exe, etc) are present in scripts folder inside 'Roaming' folder and not inside 'local' folder.

[image]

python version: *3.8.4* 
pip version: *20.1.1*

Comment: Any problems with packages? What is `python -m pip check` giving you? Any missing deps?

Comment: you should install anaconda first, then you will automatically get jupyter notebook

Comment: Could you please post the output of `pip freeze`? or Can you make sure `jupyter` package is in the list?

Comment: @AhmetTavli I see `jupyterlab==2.2.1` , `jupyterlab-server==1.2.0` and `notebook==6.0.3` in output of `pip freeze`

[pip freeze output](https://i.imgur.com/pTnaOAl.png)

Comment: @DawidGacek thanks! that worked. I got the list of missing dependencies with I  installed and it worked! Can you add that as an answer so that I can accept it to help other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had worked with Jupyter Notebook and usually the cause for most of the cases is missing dependecy - Jupyter got a lot of them.

Please check if they are not missing by running:

```py
python -m pip check
```

or

```py
pip check
```

This will give you list of missed (sometimes there are versions problems) dependencies. Installing proper version with `pip install <dep>==<version>` should help.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `python3 -m notebook` in the terminal.

Comment: Would be great to have a bit more explanation about why this resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
@Divyessh Maheshwari, if you have installed anaconda, then make sure you are running `jupyter notebook` in the anaconda prompt.

If you haven't and you don't want to install anaconda, you might need to downgrade Python according to this answer [Is there a way to run Jupyter Notebooks Without Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59726749/is-there-a-way-to-run-jupyter-notebooks-without-anaconda)

Comment: if he had anaconda then why would he download jupyter as a seperate file

Comment: No, It's just windows 10. no anaconda.

Comment: The newest version of the Jupyter notebook should be fine with py 3.8. Try `pip install notebook --upgrade` to install the newest version

Comment: @James yes, but I already tried it. Mine is the most recent version of notebook. I feel it's more of a `Environment Variable` issue.

Answer (score 0):

It worked to me using: python3 -m notebook
in terminal, then:
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///C:/Users/Sorin/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-6104-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8888/?token=13028604333fbe9766eb5c0f2668378a05d0712ef08891a7
or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=13028604333fbe9766eb5c0f2668378a05d0712ef08891a7

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In the question, it seems like the poster already tried `python -m notebook` as suggested by pratsy's answer and got `ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython'`.

Comment: (Also, those tokens won't work on somebody else's computer, and while it won't matter for a local jupyter instance, definitely be careful posting auth tokens on the public internet!)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33916262)